# improving theorem environment

Tags: environments

The following is a theorem from Algebraic topology written by A. Hatcher.

I'm interested in to know how is possible do theorems like this:
[image]

I know that a new environment has the following form, how to put two vertical lines. Thanks

```
\newtheoremstyle{stylename}{spaceabove}{spacebelow}{bodyfont}{indent}{headfont}{headpunctuation}{headspace}{headspec}
```

Comment: `mdframed` is the better one

Comment: Thesmall  `framed` package defines a `leftbar` environment. You also can look at the `thmtools` package.

Comment: @MadyYuvi thanks. this package is awesome.

Comment: @Bernard thmtools package is great. Thanks

Comment: You can use the lettrine package for the big T in Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several people have suggested packages such as `thmtools` in the comments.  If you want to roll your own, here is a wrapper around an existing environment.  It supports an optional argument, but cannot break across pages.  It’s therefore only appropriate for short theorems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm} % For \newtheorem*.
\usepackage{unicode-math}    % Or your math package of choice.
\usepackage{xparse}          % For \NewDocumentEnvironment.
\usepackage{settobox}        % For \settoboxtotalheight.
\usepackage{microtype}       % For font expansion.
\usepackage{lipsum}          % For \lipsum.

%% This is the font actually used within the example you gave:
%\setmainfont{Cambria}
%\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}

\newsavebox{\decothmbox}
\newlength{\decowidth}
\newlength{\decoheight}
\newlength{\decorulewidth}
\setlength{\decorulewidth}{1.5em}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{decothm}{mo}%
  {%
\bigskip\par\noindent%
\setlength{\decowidth}{\hsize}%
\addtolength{\decowidth}{-1.0\decorulewidth}%
\begin{lrbox}{\decothmbox}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{\decowidth}%
\begin{#1}[#2]}%
  {%
\end{#1}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}%
\settoboxtotalheight{\decoheight}{\decothmbox}%
\makebox[\decorulewidth]{%
\hspace{0.6em}%
\rule{0.1em}{\decoheight}%
\hspace{0.1em}%
\rule{0.05em}{\decoheight}%
\hspace{0.65em}}%
\usebox{\decothmbox}%
\bigskip\par}

\begin{document}
This is a theorem.

\begin{decothm}{thm*}[4L.9]\label{thm:example}
Suppose \(H^\ast (X ; \mathbb{Z}_p)\) is the polynomial algebra
\(\mathbb{Z}_p[\alpha]\) on a generator \(\alpha\) of dimension \(n\),
possibly truncated by the relation \(\alpha^m = 0\) for \(m > p\).  Then if
\(p = 2\), \(n\) must be a power of \(2\), and if \(p\) is an odd prime, \(n\)
must be of the form \(p^k \ell\), where \(\ell\) is an even divisor of
\(2(p-1)\).
\end{decothm}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Theorem layout sample]

Essentially, this typesets the theorem text inside a `minipage` that subtracts the width of the left rule.  Instead of using it immediately, we save that in a box so we can measure its height.  This lets us lay out the rules to the left first.

The code uses `xparse` to make it possible to use an argument in the code to close an environment, `settobox` as a convenient way to add the height and the depth of the theorem, and includes `amsmath` before `amsthm` because, otherwise, another package would have loaded it afterwards, which could have caused bugs in a more complex document.