# Help with creating a thick vertical line to reproduce a Word document Template

Tags: minipage

[image: How can I recreate this?]

I'm trying to recreate this formatting from a template a professor requires to use for writing his homework, but can't figure out how to do it.

Can minipage environment achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Could you show us a bit of what you tried in this respect ?  In that way it would be much easier for others to point out _exactly_ what you need-- rather than building an example from scratch !

Comment: You might adapt [this environment wrapper I wrote for theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547496/improving-theorem-environment/547527#547527), since it’s general. Yes, it puts the text inside a minipage. However, it’s not a great approach for this because it can’t paginate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a side bar to any paragraph using [changebar](https://ctan.org/pkg/changebar?lang=en) package by the command `\usepackage{changebar}`. The default of the package is adding the side bar to the right, so you may need to use the option `[leftbars]`.

The output you get is like this

[image]

Here is the minimal code example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leftbars]{changebar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Paragraph with no side bar}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Paragraph with a side bar}
\cbstart
\lipsum[1]
\cbend
\end{document}
```

---

You can further change the color and thickness of the sidebar line using, for example

```
\cbcolor{red} % line color
\setlength\changebarwidth{5pt} % line thickness
```

before `\cbstart` command, so in that case you get something like this

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for this! This package is exactly what I was looking for. Amazing how there's always a package that solves our issues.

Comment: If you think an answer solves your problem, you may click accept this answer and up-vote it (the option up left-side of any answer) so that other people may use it and understand that it was useful. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new here in stackexchange. I tried upvoting it but I don't have enough points to upvote. Didn't see the accept answer at the time. All is good now. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Your welcome and don't worry, soon you will have enough points. It's nice to see people sharing their experience with each others.